# How to get latest posts in vbulletin with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get latest posts of vbulletin hack from this website:

http://ashiyane.org/forums/

and here is my try:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf -*- 

import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://ashiyane.org/forums/'
connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = connection.read()
connection.close()

    # End the connection

data_html = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
data_area = data_html.find(id='vietvbb_topstats_t_content')
title_rows = data_area.find('span', 'topx-content-tab')

for link in title_rows.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))


# testing the <a and href tag ...
# for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    #print(link.get('href'))
```

`for` from:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

but after running, here is the result:

```
showthread.php?148716-something&s=6d9b5c706c6c6f76599018eaf55a60a5&goto=newpost
```

**and it's returns the one of the values of these 15 result.**

So, what is wrong?

Comment: it seems after **find_all** nothing works.And that's the reason because i need to find_all first from `span` -> `topx-content-tab` and then form `a` -> `href` getting text.Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are getting title_rows you are getting just one row not set of rows.So you can use following code which  is returning 15 result as per your requirement.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://ashiyane.org/forums/'
connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = connection.read()
connection.close()

    # End the connection

data_html = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
data_area = data_html.find(id='vietvbb_topstats_t_content')
#title_rows = data_area.find('span', 'topx-content-tab')
title_rows = data_area.findAll("span", { "class" : "topx-content-tab" })


for link in title_rows:
    print link.find_all("a")
```

Comment: great, tnx :) intresting method.